# Comparing generic types (extends vs implements and within the context of LinkedList using nodes private class)

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I have a standard LinkedList class with nodes that have data fields of generic type and I'm trying to compare them but not sure how I should go about it.

My node class

```
private static class Node<E> 
{
    E data;
    Node<E> prev;
    Node<E> next;
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to do

```
if(nodeA.data > newData)
     //do something
```

Should I be doing something like

```
public class MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable <E>>
```

or
`public class MyLinkedList<E> implements Comparable <E>`

And for both ways, do I implement my own compareTo method?
I've tried this but the compareTo usually looks like

```
public int compareTo(E data)
{
    if(this > data)
        return 1;
    //add others
}
```

And here, the 'this' would refer to my LinkedList class, not the generic type E.

Thank you

Comment: It's a good practice in cases like these to stop and make sure you can express specifically what your constraints are. You aren't trying to _compare lists_, you want to _compare elements inside the list_, and your type information (specifically what is `Comparable`) should reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the data contained in the node, then `public class MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>` is the way to go, since this guarantees that the generic type `E` provides a `compareTo(...)`-method. In this case, implementing the `compareTo`-method is a job for the developer writing the type.

If you define `public class MyLinkedList<E> implements Comparable<E>` then you make a node comparable to `E`, but since `E` is unbound, it basically gets erased to `Object` <s>and this really would not give you any real possibility to compare objects</s>. Since one can access the variable of type `E` only as if it were an `Object`, one basically has no access to relevant information to implement a meaningful order. I would question such an order, or at least ask for the specific use case for this order.

---

---

Two Remarks:

Since Java does not support operator overloading, one cannot write

```
nodeA.data > something
```

but call the `compareTo`-Method and evaluate its return value, e.g.:

```
nodeA.data.compareTo(something) > 0
```

---

There is also another way to allow types that do not implement `Comparable` by enforcing that a `Comparator<E>` is passed along. [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) uses this approach.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219138/discussion-on-answer-by-turing85-comparing-generic-types-extends-vs-implements).

Comment: @BrianGoetz's [*1*](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2075692/avoid-synchronization-deadlocks.html#104b9f89-5d50-4c5a-ba78-519d7f595b41): „*If the object...lacks a natural identity property like an account number, you can use the Object.identityHashCode() method to generate one*“ + Goetz's [*2*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3650/4bc31d3b2c5c00e5bfee28ffc5d403cc8edd.pdf?_ga=2.106723911.535573105.1596451818-1030115882.1596451818):  „*...One way to induce an ordering on objects is to use `System.identityHashCode`...*“ + my [*3*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/8d) shows Turing85's statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've completely misunderstood your question, then since you said…

> *Basically, I'm trying to do*
>
> ```
> if(nodeA.data > newData)
>      //do something
> ```

…then to me it makes more sense to have the type parameter of your *`Node`* implement *`Comparable`* instead of the one of your *`List`*…

```
public class LinkedList<E>{ 

    public static class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> {

        E data;

        Node<E> next;

        Node<E> prev;


        Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {

            this.data = element;

            this.next = next;

            this.prev = prev;

        }
    
        public E getData( ){ return this.data; }

    }
}
```

Then whatever your *`data`* is, it would have to *`implement Comparable`*…

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>{ 
    
    private int x;
    
    public Foo(int x){ this.x = x; }
    
    public int compareTo(Foo that){ 
        return this.x < that.x ? -1 : this.x == that.x ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

…allowing you to do something closer to what you specified with your *`if(nodeA.data > newData)`* pseudocode…

```
public class DeduperAnswer{ 
    
    static public void main(String... args){ 
        
        LinkedList.Node<Foo> node1 = new LinkedList.Node<>(null, new Foo(10), null);
        LinkedList.Node<Foo> node2 = new LinkedList.Node<>(null, new Foo(20), null);
 
        if (node2.getData().compareTo(node1.getData()) > 0){ 
            /* ...this is NOT how you'd use it, of course...*/
        }
    }
}
```

You can see [*a quick and dirty working example here*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_304623).

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR***: It is absolutely possible to compare two *`Comparable`* parameterized instantiations of some generic type *`T<E>`* regardless of type erasure.

---

[*One answer said*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63209455/2)…

> „*…but since `E` is unbound, it basically gets erased to `Object` and this really would not give you any real possibility to compare objects*…“

[*Type erasure happens*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6). However — *at least in the context of the quoted hypothesis above* — type erasure is not the issue in that context. The issue in that context and in that of the original question is: *`E` will ultimately be some specific type when a given parameterized type is instantiated by an actual type argument at the use site*.

@Turing85's hypothesis raises this question:

***Q***: *Whatever the ultimate type of `E` is, is it mandatory for it to implement `Comparable` in order for there to be „any real possibility to compare objects“?*

***A***:  ***No***. In the context of the original question, it's not about *`E`* implementing *`Comparable`*. In that context, it's about *`MyLinkedList`* implementing *`Comparable`*.

Declaring a generic class with an unbound type parameter *`E`* does not preclude the possibility to compare objects. For example there could be some use case where it's necessary to have *`MyLinkedList<MyLinkedList<Foo>>`*; where the ***unbounded*** *`E`* is *`MyLinkedList<Foo>`* in the outer parameterized type and the ***unbounded*** *`E`* is *`Foo`* in the inner parameterized type.

In [*this working demonstration*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_304753) I've implemented a ***simplified*** representative model of a linked list. In my simplified model,*`Bar`* does not implement *`Comparable`*.  *`MyLinkedList<E>`* itself does implement *`Comparable<E>`* though.

A usage example…

```
public class Bar { 

    private int y;

    public Bar(int y){ 
        this.y = y;
    }               
}
...
MyLinkedList<Bar> list1 = new MyLinkedList<>();
MyLinkedList<MyLinkedList<Bar>> list2 = new MyLinkedList<>();
MyLinkedList<Bar> list3 = new MyLinkedList<>();
...
list1.add(new Bar(100));
list2.add(list3);  
list3.add(new Bar(101));
...
if (list2.compareTo(list1) != 0){ ... }
...
```

Click the green ***Start*** button at the top of [*the demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_304753). Then you can observe that it doesn't matter that *`E`* has no bounds in the declaration of *`MyLinkedList<E>`*. It does not matter that *`Bar`* does not implement *`Comparable`*.

It is absolutely possible to compare two *`Comparable`* parameterized instantiations of *`MyLinkedList<E>`* with no problem…

```
...
[node -> [node -> Bar: y=101]] is greater than [node -> Bar: y=100]
...
```

It's worth repeating: In my demonstration model, *`Bar`* does not implement *`Comparable`*.

It's worth pointing out too that regardless of type erasure, what's observed in *`stdout`* shows that whatever the runtime type of the *`node`* displayed here is, it has all the public, non-static members of type *`Bar`*.

Comment: There is a comment under my answer that points out the possibility of writing an order, but I would question its semantics. My exact wording in the comment is: "*... The problem is that there is no semantically relevant information one can get from the data field, since it can only be accessed as if it were an Object.*"

Comment: „_...The problem is that there is no semantically relevant information one can get from the data field, since it can only be accessed as if it were an Object..._“ — @Turing85 _`Bar`_ is a ***simplifying model*** for the _`data`_ of a _`Node`_. How do you explain _`Bar.x`_ being accessible? What makes _`Bar.x`_ „*semantically irrelevant*“? Please understand: I'm not *arguing*; I'm just trying to grok your hypothesis. Namely: „*but since `E` is unbound, it basically gets erased to `Object` and this really would not give you any real possibility to compare objects...*“

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "*`Bar.x` being accessible*"? Where exactly do you mean it is accessible? It is not accessible within `MyLinkedList`. Shall we continue the discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219107/room-for-turing85-and-deduper)?

Comment: Oops! _`Bar.y`_ I should say. My mistake —  „*It is not accessible within `MyLinkedList`*“ — You are correct that _`Bar.y`_ is not accessible to the outermost list of  _`MyLinkedList<MyLinkedList<Bar>>`_. But _`Bar.y`_ ***is*** accessible to the innermost _`MyLinkedList<Bar>`_; as the _`MyLinkedList.node`_ field. The innermost _`MyLinkedList<Bar>`_ ***list*** is accessible to the outermost _`MyLinkedList<...>`_ as its _`node`_ field. [*You can observe*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_304753) that each list's _`node`_ field is printed to _`stdout`_.

Comment: Again, [let us continue the discussoin in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219108/discussion-between-turing85-and-deduper).